# error when compiling kernel with some new features

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to compile kernel version 4.1 with [some patches](https://github.com/gengyl08/juggler) (adding some features to the GRO). I come from a hardware background and relatively new to network stack. I wish to know how to solve this problem or at least pointers to understand why it occurs.

This is what I did

```
# my temp location

mdkir kern
cd kern

# cloned the juggler and linux 4.1 tree

git clone https://github.com/gengyl08/juggler.git
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf linux-4.1.tar.gz

# copied just the essential files that were diffferent

cp juggler/linux-4.1/include/linux/netdevice.h linux-4.1/include/linux/netdevice.h
cp juggler/linux-4.1/include/linux/skbuff.h linux-4.1/include/linux/skbuff.h
cp juggler/linux-4.1/net/core/dev.c linux-4.1/net/core/dev.c
cp juggler/linux-4.1/net/core/net-sysfs.c linux-4.1/net/core/net-sysfs.c
cp juggler/linux-4.1/net/core/skbuff.c linux-4.1/net/core/skbuff.c
cp juggler/linux-4.1/net/ipv4/af_inet.c linux-4.1/net/ipv4/af_inet.c
cp juggler/linux-4.1/net/ipv4/tcp_offload.c linux-4.1/net/ipv4/tcp_offload.c

cd linux-4.1
make menuconfig   # generated the default .config file

# building the kernel

time make
```

When I try to compile them, I get the following error

```
drivers/net/ethernet/agere/et131x.c: In function ‘nic_send_packet.constprop.43’:
include/linux/compiler.h:412:20: error: call to ‘__compiletime_assert_2439’ declared with attribute error: BUILD_BUG
    prefix ## suffix();    \
                    ^
include/linux/compiler.h:417:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘__compiletime_assert’
  __compiletime_assert(condition, msg, prefix, suffix)
  ^
include/linux/compiler.h:429:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘_compiletime_assert’
  _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __LINE__)
  ^
include/linux/bug.h:50:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert’
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG(cond, msg) compiletime_assert(!(cond), msg)
                                     ^
include/linux/bug.h:74:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG’
  BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG(condition, "BUILD_BUG_ON failed: " #condition)
  ^
drivers/net/ethernet/agere/et131x.c:2439:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘BUILD_BUG_ON’
  BUILD_BUG_ON(MAX_SKB_FRAGS + 1 > 23);
  ^
make[4]: *** [drivers/net/ethernet/agere/et131x.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [drivers/net/ethernet/agere] Error 2
make[2]: *** [drivers/net/ethernet] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/net] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2

real    22m3.067s
user    21m4.028s
sys     1m6.724s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `MAX_SKB_FRAGS` is too big and ethernet driver doesn't like it.

[From `drivers/net/ethernet/agere/et131x.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/agere/et131x.c?v=4.1):

```
/* Part of the optimizations of this send routine restrict us to
 * sending 24 fragments at a pass.  In practice we should never see
 * more than 5 fragments.
 */

/* nr_frags should be no more than 18. */
BUILD_BUG_ON(MAX_SKB_FRAGS + 1 > 23);
```

From the patches you're using:

`linux-3.18.5/include/linux/skbuff.h`:

```
#if (65536/PAGE_SIZE + 1) < 16
#define MAX_SKB_FRAGS 16UL
#else
#define MAX_SKB_FRAGS (65536/PAGE_SIZE + 1)
#endif
```

`linux-4.1/include/linux/skbuff.h`:

```
#if (65536/PAGE_SIZE + 1) < 45
#define MAX_SKB_FRAGS 45UL
#else
#define MAX_SKB_FRAGS (65536/PAGE_SIZE + 1)
#endif
```

Note the difference.

I haven't analyzed this code, but from a very first look I see some inconsistency there.

Replacing *45* back to *16* should do the trick. Of course, there might be a reason why the patch author picked a higher value.

Comment: Thanks Andrejs. Will check it and return.